# Inner and outer linearization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

Why are Dantzig-Wolfe and Benders decomposition referred to as inner and outer linearization respectively?

I am a newbie in Mathematical Programming and optimization and came across these terms while reading "Introduction to Stochastic Programming" by Birge and Louveaux.